# About an error encountered during code analysis for conversion to ColdFusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion

After using the code analyzer of ColdFusion 2016 on our code base it is giving us the following error.

> No _ [B5O] Incorrect usage of WRITELOG function.WRITELOG function can not be used in substitution statements.

```
<cfoutput>#writeLog("DS001", "#This.Name#", "SDC601", ArrayNew(1))#</cfoutput>
```

What does this error mean?  What do I need to do in order to fix the issue?

We are migrating from ColdFusion 7 to ColdFusion 2016.

Answer (score 0):

How/Why are you using `<cfscript>` syntax within `<cfoutput>` tags? If your code is within `<cfscript>` tags then `<cfoutput>` tags would be invalid. Anyway those tags are not needed when calling the `writelog` or `<cflog>` function. This leads me to believe the code that you shared is not the actual code.

It seems that your values for the function call are incorrect. Not sure how that worked in ColdFusion 7 either (again, this is probably not an example of the actual code). Here is an excerpt [from the documentation for the writelog function](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/writelog.html):

> Function syntax
>
> ```
> WriteLog (text, type, application, file, log)
> ```
>
> For positional notation, the sequence must be followed exactly in the same manner as provided in the syntax. If you do not provide one of the parameters, use an empty string instead. This does not apply to Boolean values for which you must provide proper values even if you have to skip them.

The code you shared is:

```
writeLog("DS001", "#This.Name#", "SDC601", ArrayNew(1))
```

Which means you are using positional notation and ColdFusion is interpreting that as:

```
text        = "DS001"
type        = "#This.Name#"
application = "SDC601"
file        = ArrayNew(1)
log         =
```

The code needs to be modified to pass the values in the correct order when using that syntax. And I'm not sure why you are attempting to pass an empty array into the function. None of the attributes accept an array.